# Update context when state object mutates

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, state

I have a `PageContext` that is holding the state of `User` objects as array. Each `User` object contains a `ScheduledPost` object that does mutate when user decides to add a new post. I have no idea how to trigger an update on my `PageContext` when it happens (I want to avoid `forceUpdate()` call). I need to somehow be notified of that, in order to re-render posts, maintain timer etc.

Please, see the code:

```
class User {
    name: string;
    createTime: number;
    scheduledPosts: ScheduledPost[] = [];

    /*
     * Creates a new scheduled post
     */
    public createScheduledPost(title : string, content : string, date : number): void {
        this.scheduledPosts.push(Object.assign(new ScheduledPost(), {
            title,
            content,
            date
        }));
    }
}

class ScheduledPost {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    date: number;

    public load(): void {
        // Create timers etc.
    }

    public publish(): void {
        // Publish post
    }
}

// PageContext/index.tsx
export default React.createContext({
    users: [],
    editingUser: null,
    setEditingUser: (user: User) => {}
});

// PageContextProvider.tsx
const PageContextProvider: React.FC = props => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
    const [editingUser, setEditingUser] = useState<User>(null);

    // Load users
    useEffect(() => {
        db.getUsers()
            .then(result => setUsers(result));
    }, []);

    return (
        <PageContext.Provider value={{
            users,
            editingUser,
            setEditingUser
        }}>
            {props.children}
        </PageContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

What I would like to achieve is, when consuming my provider with `useContext` hook:

```
const ctx = useContext(PageContext);
```

I would like to create a schedule post from any component like so:

```
// Schedule post (1 hour)
ctx.editingUser.createScheduledPost("My post title", "The post content", (new Date).getTime() + 1 * 60 * 60);
```

However, this wont work, since React doesn't know that `User` property has just mutated.

---

### Questions:

- How can I make React being notified of the changes within any of the `User` object instance? What is the way to solve it properly (excluding forceUpdate)?
- Am I doing it right? I'm new to React and I feel like the structure I'm using here is cumbersome and just not right.

Comment: Can you provide an working example? Like codesanbox?

Comment: Use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) and store the user as an object (serializable).

Answer (score 3):

Where are the users being mutated? If you're storing them in your state as it appears, the changes should be detected.  However if you're using the methods built into the User class to let them [directly update](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/) themselves, then React will not pick up on them. You would need to update the entire `users` array in your state to make sure React can respond to the changes.

It's tough to give a more specific example without seeing exactly where/how you're updating your users currently, but a generalized mutation might go something like this (you can still use a class method, if desired):

```
const newUsers = Array.from(users); // Deep copy users array to prevent direct state mutation.
newUsers[someIndex].createScheduledPost(myTitle, myContent, myDate);
setUsers(newUsers); // Calling the setX function tied to your useState call will automatically trigger updates/re-renders for all (unless otherwise specified) components/operations that depend on it
```

Comment: But it makes no sense to update the array in such case. Is this really the way everyone goes in React? This is against performance so bad. Having some C# background and instance-based objects, this turns to be cumbersome. Can you show an example of how am I supposed to add a scheduled post, so that every component that makes use of the context, will receive updated array?

Comment: In this instance, I agree that it can be counter-intuitive coming from a language like C#, and is not as performant as a singular update or splice, etc.  But yes, this is a fundamental principle of React: data stored in state must be updated with ```setState``` (or in hooks ```setX```) so that React can "react" to the changes properly.  It confers a large number of performance [benefits](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) as well, and the complication of rendering the DOM changes the calculus a bit as opposed to a static data object on the back end.

Comment: I will update my answer with how this can be done, but to answer your question: the users array will be automatically updated in your context as you are passing it down directly from the state, provided that you are updating it with the ```setUsers``` function.

Comment: Yes, that would be amazing if you could elaborate on this `update the entire users array in your state to make sure React can respond to the changes` what steps should I take to instead maintain individual `User` state in the `User` class directly, because as far as the `User` class is not a React component, I cannot use `useState` hook within that class. Perhaps some sort of store would be possible with proper subscribe event?

Comment: I added a general example of how you could update the ```users``` state using your class method, but you could do almost any operation(s) between the first and third steps using the cloned array.

Comment: (1/2) I understand the state mutation and all that, but when it's gets really cumbersome for me is when trying to keep it working with OOP. Consider I want to mutate a property in the `scheduledPosts`. That would be: `users[someIndex].scheduledPosts[someOtherIndex].title = "New title";`. Every time I do so I have to set a new `users` array copy in order for the changes to be reflected in React components. So the question that remains is, what is the best way for the state mutation to happen "behind the scenes". I can think of doing a `setTitle` method, where state would be updated accordingly

Comment: (2/2) ... but this is where it gets messed up: `Users` and `ScheduledPosts` classes aren't React components, so I'm unable to use hooks or access the state of any kind; I have to rely on callbacks or events in the `PageContextProvider`, this is where I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In React re-render is caused by calling `setState` within component (or by using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), but the point is that you need to call specific method) or by changing component `props`. That means that manual mutation of your state will never cause a re-render - even if you had simple component and called

`this.state.something = somethingElse;`

re-render would not occur. Same thing works for context.

For your case, this means that you should not mutate `editingUser` state, but call `setEditingUser` with changed user state, something like:

```
const user = { ...ctx.editingUser };
user.createScheduledPost("My post title", "The post content", (new Date).getTime() + 1 * 60 * 60);
ctx.setEditingUser(user);
```

I'm not sure about your inner structure, but if that same user is also in `users` array, then you'll need to update that part of state by calling `setUsers` method where you maintain whole array and only update that single user which changed data - if thats the case then I'd think about restructuring the app because it already gets complicated for such simple state changes. You should also consider using [redux](https://mobx.js.org), [mobx](https://mobx.js.org) or some other state management library instead of react context (my personal advice).

**EDIT**

Please take a look at this quite:

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
>   child) via props, but this can be cumbersome for certain types of
>   props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
>   components within an application. Context provides a way to share
>   values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
>   a prop through every level of the tree.

As you can see, react team is suggesting using context for some global preferences that are required within many components. The main problem with using context (in my opinion) is that you don't write *natural* react components - they don't receive dependant data through props but rather from within the context api itself. This means that you won't be able to reuse your components without also integrating context part of application.

While for example redux has similar concept of keeping state at one place, it still propagades that state (and its changes) to components via props, making your components undependent of both redux, context or anything else.

You can stick to react context and make whole app work with it, but I'm just saying it wouldn't be best practice to do so.